# Python 3.3 - Send variable to thread

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, python-3.3

I'm not sure if this is best practice or anything, but I have a thread running that activates every 5 seconds checking for a parameter in a list, outside of that thread I have a while loop running that will insert the parameter into the list using a function outside of the while loop (this part works as it should), however the list doesn't update inside of the thread, how would I send this into the thread?

IE

```
def addtolist():
    mylist.extend([variable])

def myfunction():
    while True:
        if time.time() > 5 + last_time:
            last_time = time.time()
            print(mylist[0]) # doesn't print anything
        time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    count_job = Thread(target = myfunction, args = ())
    count_job.start()

while True:
    variable = "Look, a fly!"
    addtolist()
    time.sleep(7)
```

I mean it's a quite bit more complicated than that and way too long to paste in here but this is the part that I've just added that isn't working, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your thread function exits immediately... it performs a single check of the time, prints the first element of `mylist` depending on the initial value of `last_time` and exits.

Aside from the fact that your example code does not show how/where the variables are initialised, your thread function needs to look something like this:

```
def myfunction():
    while True: # loop forever
        if time.time() > 5 + last_time:
            last_time = time.time()
            print(mylist[0]) # doesn't print anything
        time.sleep(1) # wait for one second for mylist to be updated, yield to main thread
```

Note if you do not add a `sleep` in the thread, it will wait in a busy loop without returning control to the main thread (and consume a great deal of CPU).

Also, note that the thread will always print the same value (the first element of `mylist`). Since `addtolist` appends to the end of the list, new values will not be displayed. You may want to change `print(mylist[0])` to `print(mylist[-1])` to display the last inserted elements.

Finally, there are much better ways of doing this. See [docs.python.org/3.3/library/threading.html](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/threading.html) under section *17.1.5. Condition Objects*.

Comment: forgot to add thread does have a while True loop already in it, will update my post, my mistake

Comment: then you are in a busy loop... trying adding the `sleep` statement as in my answer and see if the result is different.

Comment: there is a time.sleep(1) in my loop...sigh I'll add that as well

Comment: come on, if you ask a question, at least show the problem code!!! this works for me: http://pastebin.com/AtpLQ7nt. prints `first` every 5 seconds.

Comment: :-/ looks like when I set it as a global function it works for me, thanks for bearing with me and giving me that example

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you another aproach for implementing threads that has some state. Do not use globals, use `threading.Thread` inheritance instead.

For instance, your problem can be solved this way:

```
import threading
import time


class MyThread(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, some_list=None):
        super(MyThread, self).__init__()
        self.list = some_list if some_list is not None else []
        self.event = threading.Event()     # Used for stop the thread

    def run(self):
        while not self.event.isSet():
            # Do your thread thing here.
            time.sleep(1)
            print(self.list)


    def add_elem(self, elem):
        self.list.append(elem)  # Extend or append, is up to you.

    def stop(self):
        self.event.set()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    thread = MyThread()     # Thread instance.
    thread.start()          # Start the thread.
    thread.add_elem(10)     # Add some element.
    time.sleep(3)           # Wait 3 secs.
    thread.add_elem(100)    # Add another element.
    time.sleep(3)           # Wait 3 secs.
    thread.stop()           # Stop thread.
```

This way you can even add more "behaviour" to your thread, you might add functions like `remove`, `sort`, etc...

On the other hand, if you are executing tasks that get executed past some time(5 secs in your case) you should consider use [Timers Objects](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/timer-objects.html)